# Line breaks inside multirow does not make cell bigger

Tags: tables, line-breaking, multirow, makecell

I have some long lines in a table and I am using `\makecell` to add in line breaks. Usually this works fine (vertically centres the text and expands the cell to fit), but I need this inside of a multirow and the cell does not expand to fit the text. Below is an MWB showing the behaviour along with the output.

I tried using a tabular environment inside and outside the multirow but I could not get that to work. I also tried using `{c|p{2cm}|c|c|}` and specifying the width of the column in the multirow command. One thing that did work was specifying the height of the each row with `\\[8pt]`, but then the text is not vertically centred.

Ideally I would like a solution where the cell dimensions are automatic and I only need to manually specify the line breaks, but any solution will do. The second picture is the output I want (made in Excel).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Line 1\\Line 2}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Line 1\\Line 2\\Line 3}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Wide Line}  \\
        \cline{3-4}
         & & A & B \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output from minimum working example]
[image: Ideal output]

Comment: Have a look at the tabularray package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={*4c}, vlines, hlines, hspan=even, vspan=even}
        \SetCell[r=2]{c}{Line 1\\Line 2} & \SetCell[r=2]{c}{Line 1\\Line 2\\Line 3} & \SetCell[c=2]{c}{Wide Line} & \\
        & & A & B \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice answer (+1). However, you my consider to add `vspan=even` option too!

Comment: @Zarko Done, thank you!